How to prove the convergence of the following series involving Gamma function?
Consider the following result（$d$ denotes the dimensions and $0<t<T$）
$$c\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma^j(1-\kappa)}{\Gamma((j+1)(1-\kappa))}t^{j(1-\kappa)-\kappa}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq c t^{-\frac{\kappa}{2}}, \text{ where } \frac{\kappa}{2}=\frac{d}{\alpha}-\frac{d}{2q\alpha}, \alpha+d\geq \frac{\alpha+d}{2q} ，0<\alpha\leq 2， \text{ and } 2q>1,$$
which appears in the article Quantitative normal approximations for the stochastic fractional heat equation.
I notice that it only takes the term of $j=0$. I try to use the conclusion $\Gamma(z)\sim z^{z-1/2}e^{-z}$, and prove it by considering the rapid decrease. But I don't know if it is true and how to explain it convincingly.

To simplify the question, why don't you divide by $c$,  square, and multiply by $t^\kappa$ both sides? And maybe call $s:=t^{\kappa-1}$.

Also, $\alpha, d, q, t$ are completely useless as the information is not enough. Why don't you just cut them from the question and say in what range you want $\sigma:=1-\kappa $ and $\tau:=\Gamma(1-\kappa)t^{1-\kappa}$?

So the question reads: is $\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{\tau^j}{\Gamma((j+1)\sigma)}\leq1$ for $\tau$,$\sigma$ in the prescribed range?

Thank you so much Professor Pietro Majer for your advice. But the corresponding series is not geometric progression as I expected. How can I get its bound ？

Note that for $\sigma=1$ you get $e^\tau$. In general you may use the Stirling formula

Thank you Professor Pietro Majer. I find it is true that the series can be seen as the exponential function when I take a special $\sigma=1$， i.e. $\kappa=0$. But the upper bound is not 1. And I am still confused what if $0<\sigma<1$?

You should use the Stirling bounds on $\Gamma$. For $0<\sigma<1$,  one has $\Gamma(\sigma)>1$, so the term of the series for $j=0$ is less than 1, which I guess make it possible the bound 1 for small t.
